# JQuery - If DIV ID is Visible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to find out of a DIV is hidden or if it is exposed.

This is the pseudocode:

```
if(DIV != VISIBLE) // not visible
{
  show content
}
```

Any JQuery Experts able to assist me?

Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 44):

If you're trying to *just* show a div which is hidden, then you don't actually need to do any checks at all:

```
$('#myDiv').show();
```

Regardless of its state beforehand, it'll end up visible now.

However, if you want to perform other actions depending on whether the content is visible or not, then you'll need to check:

```
if ($('#myDiv').is(":hidden")) 
// or
if ($('#myDiv:hidden').length) 
// or
if ($('#myDiv:not(:visible)')) {    // you get the idea...
    //perform your actions
}
```

Comment: I can't guarantee the sanctity of this test, but I just threw these three functions into jsperf to see what came up..  Seems like .is:hidden is the best!
http://jsperf.com/is-the-div-hidden

Answer (score 31):

All other answers are fine, but this is just to translate your pseudocode into actual javascript code:

```
if (!$('div').is(':visible')) {
  $('div').show();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The following will display a DIV named `myDiv` if it is hidden.  Note that if you want to do other stuff, you can also use each() rather than show and do other operations on $(this) inside each.

```
$('div#myDiv:hidden').show();
```

Comment: that's a bit redundant isn't it?

Comment: @nickf: Just trying to be consistent with the given example.

Answer (score 1):

This will test to see if you selected any hidden elements with the id "mydiv":

```
 if ( $("#mydiv:hidden").length > 0)
 {
    // 
 }
```

Edit: Simplified selector. Had to look it up :/

Answer (score 0):

If you're only looking to hiding and showing an element you might as well just use jQuery [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method that will do just that for you. Similarly, [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) and .fadeToggle() methods will hide and show element(s) with either slide or fade animation.